# Using filter on an object sub-property array?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I'm trying to do a fancy filter on an object that's used in an ng-options.

My ng-options call:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="type" ng-options="k as v.display for (k, v) in ssidTypes"></select>
```

And below is the object that's getting passed in.

```
$scope.ssidTypes = {
    "CPE": {
        display: "Fixed/CPE",
        features: {
            CI: false,
            SSIDVLAN: true,
            CPEVLAN: true
        },
        intfs: [5],
        modes: ["tdma", "csma"],
    },
    "Hotspot": {
        display: "Hotspot",
        features: {
            CI: true,
            SSIDVLAN: true,
            CPEVLAN: false
        },
        intfs: [2, 5],
        modes: ['csma']
    },
    "Trunk": {
        display: "Trunk",
        features: {
            CI: false,
            SSIDVLAN: false,
            CPEVLAN: false
        },
        intfs: [5],
        modes: ['tdma', 'csma']
    }
};
```

What I'm trying to is filter out options based upon the `intfs` and `modes` property of the objects.

Meaning when I have:

```
$scope.intf = 5;
```

I would like the options to only be the ones that have 5 in the `intf` array.

I'm hoping there's some way to do `| filter:{something something here}` that could magically do this for me.

Comment: You have to write a custom filter to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

A simple custom filter should do it, just as you would otherwise return an array for a normal ng-repeat, in your case you should build an object and provide it the properties that pass

```
.filter('customFilter', function() {
    return function(data, intf) {
        var result = {}; // new empty object
        for (var key in data) {
            if (data[key].intfs.indexOf(intf) > -1) { // if number exists in array
                result[key] = data[key]; // add property to object
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
});
```

(you will probably want to add type checks and validation to this code)

HTML

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="type" ng-options="k as v.display for (k, v) in ssidTypes | customFilter: currentIntf"></select>
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/TcEFQ2cxmNhjkQsdm2c8?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom filter to achieve this.You can create a
function in your filter which will handle the key based on which you want to filer. Below filter is for `intfs` and `modes` key of your object.

**Custom Filter**:

```
app.filter('selectedTags', function() {
    return function(ssidTypes, filerval) {
        var tempArr = [];
        angular.forEach(ssidTypes, function(key, val) {
            tempArr.push(key);
        });
        return tempArr.filter(function(value) {
            //function to create filter for dynamic keys 
            function filterValue(parameter) {
                    for (var i in value[parameter]) {
                        if (filerval.indexOf(value[parameter][i]) != -1) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                //pass any key you want in your object   
                //If you want your object to be filtered based on either of the key
            if (filterValue('intfs') || filterValue('modes')) {
                return true;
            } else
                return false;
            //If you want your object to be filtered based on both of the key
            /*          if(filterValue('intfs') && filterValue('modes')) {
                          return true;
                        }
                        else
                          return false;  */
        });
    };
})
```

Pass values from your controller. You can pass any combination of the keys you want to filter.

**Controller**:

```
  $scope.filerval=[2,"csma"];
  //$scope.filerval=[2,"tdma"];
  //$scope.filerval=[5,"tdma"];
```

**HTML**

```
 <select class="form-control" ng-model="type" ng-options="k as v.display for (k, v) in ssidTypes | selectedTags:filerval"></select>
```

**Working Demo**: https://plnkr.co/edit/YFfFHAriMQqfN25Q5Pon?p=preview